# How can I get my Airport Extreme network printer working after upgrading to (K)ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, printing, 13.10

When using (K)ubuntu 13.04, my network printer worked fine. After upgrading to (K)ubuntu 13.10 today, I can no longer print. I get the error "The printer is not responding."

I've tried to add the printer again, and it is automatically recognised. I can add it, and select it from print dialogue boxes, but I get the same error.

Brother HL-2040, Kubuntu 13.10 (KDE 4.11.2)

==EDIT==

I attempted connecting the printer directly with a USB cable, and this worked fine, so it's not a problem with drivers. (FWIW I'm using the recommended HL-2040 Foomatic/hl1250.) Further, it prints fine over the network from my wife's MacBook.

==EDIT 2==

I've tried another printer over a different network, and that works fine. The one that doesn't work is connected over an Apple Airport Extreme. (Although, as stated above, it used to work fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to helpful information from the [KDE forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=118277&p=295898#p296138), it seems that Avahi/Bonjour isn't working properly. Presumably this is a regression introduced recently, although I only seem to have problems with the printer connected to the Airport Extreme.

Hence, use the IP address of the printer as specified [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/printing-to-airport-shared-printers-from-linux/2384/). i.e. add the printer as `socket://[ip address of Airport Extreme]:9100`. Fortunately for me I already had my Airport Extreme set up with a static IP, but it'd be annoying otherwise. Also, I've no idea how you'd configure it if you had two printers connected to the router.

Comment: This worked for me: `socket://192.168.102.53:9100` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's pertinent, but my network printer stopped working after the upgrade to Kubuntu 13.10 as well. On two computers. What fixed it was changing the printer driver from the recommended Postscript to CUPS+Gutenprint. Don't know why.

Comment: It doesn't seem to help in my case. I was using `HL-2040 Foomatic/hl1250 (recommended) (en)`, but there is no CUPS+Gutenprint. I tried `HL-2060 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (en)` and `HL-2035 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (en)`, but I still get the same error. (Nevertheless, have some rep for attempting to answer, and to get you started here!)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
`socket://192.168.1.5:9100`
[image: Add Airport Express printer]